# How to fix filter widget is showing on Woocommerce page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

From some reason when i add Woocommerce to a page it hide the sidebar widget.

Before adding : [page picv - before](https://prnt.sc/rd4rmt)

After adding: [page pic - after](https://prnt.sc/rd4sfb)

Any idea why?

I use TagDiv theme, WP Version 5.3.2